# Работа методов String.replaceAll & DecimalFormat.format

Tags: replace, bigdecimal

Подскажите пожалуйста по следующему вопросу:
При использовании DecimalFormat.format получаем строку отформатированную по шаблону "000 000,00". Форматируется и выводится отлично, но после этого ее нужно спарсить в BigDecimal, что не получается, видимо из-за пробелов полученных при форматировании.
Следующий шаг - попытка убрать пробелы методом replaceAll, которая почему-то оказалась безуспешной.

Пример кода:

```
public class NumFormatterTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("7564745743754354735573475.87356554");
        System.out.println(bd);  // output  7564745743754354735573475.87356554

        String stringedBd = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00").format(bd);
        System.out.println(stringedBd);  // output 7 564 745 743 754 354 735 573 475,87

        BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(stringedBd);  //NumberFormatException
        System.out.println(bd1);

        String adaptedBdd = stringedBd.replaceAll(" ", "");
        System.out.println(adaptedBdd);    // output 7 564 745 743 754 354 735 573 475,87
    }
}
```

Вопросы:

1. Почему не срабатывает replaceAll(" ", "") ? Какие спецсимволы добавляет форматтер, если не пробелы?
2. Как задать паттерн для DecimalFormat, чтобы он выводил не 2, а сколько есть символов после ',' и форматировал их так, как целую часть?

Answer (score 0):

Проблему я решил, но как-то по кривовато:

```
 int i = stringedBd.charAt(1);
 char ch = (char)i;
 String adaptedBdd = stringedBd.replaceAll(String.valueOf(ch), "");
 System.out.println(adaptedBdd);    // output 7564745743754354735573475,87
```

Буду рад получить более вразумительный вариант.